# Test database isolation with Behat 3, Doctrine 2 and Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, testing, doctrine-orm, functional-testing, behat

I am introducing functional behat tests on a Symfony2/Doctrine2 application and am deciding how to handle database isolation and data fixtures.

Are there any pitfalls to setting up a separate test environment with its own completely separate mysql database that gets populated by a dump import prior to execution of the behat test suite, and then emptied after suite execution? I'm trying to avoid using data fixtures unless I really need so as to save the time of manually writing foreign key relations and what not.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

As far as Symfony/Doctrine/Behat is concerned and if you want to be one of those who follows the best practises then:

1. You should isolate your environment dev, test, prod, stag ...
   [Setting up isolated environments as a symfony application base](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/cz5k/setting-up-isolated-environments-as-a-symfony-application-base)
   up to Build folder structure header.
2. You should isolate your test database and use sqlite instead of
   MySQL for performance purposes. [Using multiple SQLite entity
   managers for multiple bundles and databases in test environment](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/5wtr/using-multiple-sqlite-entity-managers-for-multiple-bundles-and-databases-in-test-environment),
   you can use only one.
3. You should use fixtures to give yourself flexibility and get rid of
   burden of manual processing. Do not try to avoid using them!
   [Creating doctrine data fixtures in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/fj9y/creating-doctrine-data-fixtures-in-symfony)
4. So on ..... just check the posts [in this site](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts) which I often
   read up on myself.

[Behat 3 composer entries and the behat.yml](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/5rxn/taking-screenshots-of-failed-scenarios-in-behat3)

Comment: I'd be careful with using SQLite. It is not an equivalent of MySQL, while ORMs tend to make you beileve it is. It may end up badly, especially when constraints are involved. My experience is it's hardly ever a suitable option.  Fixtures that are global to the whole test suite are also dangerous as it's exteremely easy to affect other tests unintentionally while modifying fixtures. Over time it becomes very hard to maintain. Far more maintanable and readable solution is to create fixtures in each test (not in the scenarios, in the context in case of behat).

Comment: @JakubZalas -  In layman's terms, what you're saying above applies to every tool and everybody in everyday programming. Obviously we should know when and what to/not to use which comes with experience.

Answer (score 1):

We currently have a separate test database and use a combination of both fixtures and prepopulated database.

The prepopulated database contains the minimum information that needs to be present in almost all tests. We used to do this with fixtures but it was too slow, so now we populate the DB like so:

```
/**
 * @BeforeScenario
 */
function initialiseStorage(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
{
    $con = $this->getService('database_connection');

    $con->executeUpdate("SET foreign_key_checks = 0;");

    $filePath = $this->getMinkParameter('files_path').'/test_db.sql';
    $con->exec(file_get_contents($filePath));

    $con->executeUpdate("SET foreign_key_checks = 1;");
}
```

And then, we load the specific fixtures for every test case like Alfonso described.

We use MYSQL for our tests as in our experience the bottleneck is not the DB but doctrine's metadata caching. If you set up metadata caching in redis the speed of the tests increase dramatically.

Comment: How are you able to call `$this->getService('database_connection');` in FeatureContext.php? I'm extending MinkContext.

Answer (score 1):

In order to respond to @madness-method and to complete the following answer:

> The prepopulated database contains the minimum information that needs
>   to be present in almost all tests. We used to do this with fixtures
>   but it was too slow, so now we populate the DB like so:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @BeforeScenario
>  */
> function initialiseStorage(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
> {
>     $con = $this->getService('database_connection');
>
>     $con->executeUpdate("SET foreign_key_checks = 0;");
>
>     $filePath = $this->getMinkParameter('files_path').'/test_db.sql';
>     $con->exec(file_get_contents($filePath));
>
>     $con->executeUpdate("SET foreign_key_checks = 1;");
> }
> ```
>
> And then, we load the specific fixtures for every test case like
>   Alfonso described.
>
> We use MYSQL for our tests as in our experience the bottleneck is not
>   the DB but doctrine's metadata caching. If you set up metadata caching
>   in redis the speed of the tests increase dramatically.

You should use instead:

```
/**
 * @BeforeScenario
 */
function initialiseStorage(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
{
    $con = $this->em->getConnection();

    $con->executeUpdate("SET foreign_key_checks = 0;");

    $filePath = $this->getMinkParameter('files_path').'/test_db.sql';
    $con->exec(file_get_contents($filePath));

    $con->executeUpdate("SET foreign_key_checks = 1;");
}
```

having the following code in your Context file:

```
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;

}
```

Do not forget to add the following lines in your behat configuration file regarding your contexts in order to be able to use the entity manager in your constructor and then in your *initialiseStorage* method :

```
- AppBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext:
    em: '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
```

Basically to get the connection, we have replaced:

```
$this->getService('database_connection');
```

by:

```
$this->em->getConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read something about factory girl pattern. The idea is create a 
factory for every class that you have and use a instance of it in the test. I use https://github.com/carlescliment/handy-tests-bundle

Other options will be create your own steps to create a instance or the class something like this:

```
 /**
 * @Given /^there are products:$/
 */
public function thereAreRoutes(TableNode $table)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    foreach ($table->getHash() as $hash) {
        $entity = new Product();
        $entity->setName($hash['name']);
        $entity->setDescription(isset($hash['description']) ? $hash['description'] : $hash['description']);
        $em->persist($entity);
    }

    $em->flush();
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
Given there are products:
  | name  | description |
  | Shoes | It is blue  |
```

Comment: Factory pattern is indeed a good way to do it. I'd be careful with creating steps just for the sake of populating the database. Scenarios should only contain details that are relevant for the given scenario. So, if you're not really describing a feature directly related to products, but some products need to exist, they should be created behind the scenes.